# How do I combine two date variables in Rstudio, keeping only earliest date from the two variables?

Tags: date, merge, rstudio

New to Rstudio. Using version 0.99.491 on Windows. As I use a secure server acess, I am unable to download any extra packages.

In a dataset with 450994 rows and 92 variables, I am currently using the three following variables

d$patient: id-number for patient, which is used for merging and arranging all variables.  (factor w. 320000 levels "123456789012",...:NA 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 ...)

d$utiadm: date for first admission to hospital (date, format: NA NA NA "2016-01-01" NA ...)

d$utiAB: date for first redemption of antibiotics (date, format: NA "2016-01-02" NA NA NA ...)

The dates are expressed as "YYYY-MM-DD" and I would like the new date vaiable to be the same.

Some patients have both been admitted and redeemed antibiotics, while most either have an admission OR have redeemed abtibiotics. For those having only one variable expressed, I would like to keep the date in the new variable. For the ones having both admission and antibiotics, I would like to keep the first coming date and discard the later (if they were admitted first, then I don't care that they later received antibiotics).

How do I combine two date-variables to one new date variable (d$utiall), keeping all the dates that don't overlap and only the first date where they overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone else can benefit :)

```
d$utiall <- apply(d[c('utiadm', 'utiAB')], 1, min, na.rm = T)
```

This gives a warning if some rows are NA in both variables, but just codes these rows as NA anyway.

It worked for me anyway.